# Como aumentar a distancia para aparecer ícone que expande menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Estou em um projeto MVC 4, usando bootstrap e quero saber se tem como mexer na configuração para que o botão que expande o menu (que só aparece em telas menores) apareça em algumas telas maiores.

Assim:
http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/menutoggle-png

Ali tem uma certa distância onde aquele botão do menu aparece, é essa distancia que preciso mudar.

Answer (score 5):

Este valor é definido por uma ou mais linhas similares a isto no css:

```
@media ... max-width: 1200px
```

O `min-width` e `max-width` determinam que tamanho de página receberá aquele CSS, ajustando conforme sua necessidade você muda os pontos onde a mudança de layout ocorre.

Caso você queira determinado elemento aparecendo independente de tamanho de tela, aí basta mover o trecho desejado do CSS para fora da instrução `@media { ...  }.`